# Promise Chaining: Multiple then calls

Tags: javascript, promise

What will be the output of the following snippet and why?

```
new Promise((resolve,reject) => resolve(10))
.then(data=>data*2)
.then(data=>{throw Error('error')})
.then(data=>10+10)
.catch(error=>10)
.then(data=>data*3)
.catch(error => console.error('IN ERROR',error))
.then(data=>console.log('IN DATA',data))
```

Comment: This sounds like someone's homework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`IN DATA 30`

Why? let's go one by one

1- `new Promise((resolve,reject) => resolve(10))` resolve to `10`

2- `.then(data=>data*2)` resolve to `20` (10 * 2 = 20)

3- `.then(data=>{throw Error('error')})` resolve to `error`

4- `.then(data=>10+10)` is skipped (because the prev line threw an error)

5- `.catch(error=>10)` resolve to `10`

6- `.then(data=>data*3)` resolve to `30` (3 * 10 = 30)

7- `.catch(error => console.error('IN ERROR',error))` is skipped (because the prev line has no error to be catched)

8- `.then(data=>console.log('IN DATA',data))` prints `IN DATA 30`

Answer (score 0):

```js
new Promise((resolve, reject) => resolve(10)) //Returns 10
  .then(data => data * 2) //Takes the return value, multiplies by 2 (2*10=20)
  .then(data => {
    throw Error('error')
  }) //Throws error
  .then(data => 10 + 10) //Error thrown, does not execute
  .catch(error => 10) //Resolves error with 10
  .then(data => data * 3) //Takes resolution, multiplies by 3 (3*10=30)
  .catch(error => console.error('IN ERROR', error)) //Ignored, no error thrown
  .then(data => console.log('IN DATA', data)) //Logs "IN DATA 30"
```